# Cannot Use UseBlockProps() with TypeScript - Module '"@wordpress/block-editor"' has no exported member

Tags: typescript, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to build a custom Gutenberg block using React and TypeScript. I used the [@wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) boilerplate and [this tutorial](https://mkaz.blog/wordpress/create-a-block-in-typescript/). I was able to run it, however, I get an error in Edit.tsx, on the line where I am trying to import `useBlockProps`: `Module '"@wordpress/block-editor"' has no exported member 'useBlockProps'`:

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

I have installed the following types:

```
"@types/node": "^17.0.8",
"@types/react": "^17.0.38",
"@types/wordpress__block-editor": "^6.0.4",
"@types/wordpress__blocks": "^9.1.1",
"@types/wordpress__components": "^14.0.9",
```

I am using the latest WordPress dev version - 5.9-RC2.

Comment: Running into the same issue.  Did you figure it out?